# Can not onclick in hosting php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I tried to do onclick on the select options such as the following script, when I run dilocalhost he is working but after my hosting to server he did not want work, what's wrong?

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" onchange="this.form.submit()">                       
    <?php foreach($mydata as $row) { ?>
     <option onclick='location.href="<?php echo base_url() ;?>category-all/<?php echo $row->id_data;?>"'><?php echo $row->name_data;?></option>
    <?php } ?>  
</select>
```

Comment: Look at your source code to make sure everything renders correctly. What about is not working?

Comment: she does not load the page when clicked

Comment: Does it even attempt it, or does it do nothing when you click the link? Try viewing the source code in your browser to make sure the URL looks correct.

Comment: This is a JS issue, not a CI issue.  Your onchange in the select tag is likely trumping the onclick.  Plus, an onclick for a select option likely won't do anything, because you don't have to click on the option, you select it.  try writing a function for the onchange to take your logic rather than doing a form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my environment, using CodeIgniter v3.1.2 and jQuery 3.1.1, I was able to get the following to work. With this, upon changing the select option, the window will redirect.

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#category').on('change', function() {
        location.href=this.value;
    });

});
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<select class="form-control" id="category">                       
    <?php foreach($mydata as $row) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo site_url("category-all/" . $row->id_data);?>"><?php echo $row->name_data;?></option>
    <?php } ?>  
</select>
```

Hopefully this helps the cause.